# ET.fromstring gives ParseError

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to parse an XML string and I want just the PackageReference Include attribute details and the Version of it. When I say ET.fromstring(xml) it gives error like `xml.etree.ElementTree.ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 284, column 84`. I verified if the xml is valid on multiple websites and there seems to be no issues with my xml and it is well formed.

[image: xml parse error]

Code:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    
    thisDict={}
    
    def parseXMLInCsProj(xml):
      tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
      for packageReference in tree.findall('.//PackageReference'):
         if packageReference is None:
            continue
         if 'Include' in packageReference:
            key=packageReference.get('Include')
         child_item=packageReference.find('.//Version').text
         thisDict[key]=child_item
    
    
    xmlstr=f'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Castle.Core" version="5.1.1" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="Moq" version="4.18.4" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" version="4.5.3" targetFramework="net481" />
  <package id="xunit.runner.visualstudio" version="2.4.5" targetFramework="net481" developmentDependency="true" />
</packages>'''

xmlstr1=f'''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>fdgfdgfg</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>Labcyte.Echo.Server</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>EchoServer</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <PublishUrl>publish\</PublishUrl>
    <Install>true</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <UpdateEnabled>false</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateInterval>7</UpdateInterval>
    <UpdateIntervalUnits>Days</UpdateIntervalUnits>
    <UpdatePeriodically>false</UpdatePeriodically>
    <UpdateRequired>false</UpdateRequired>
    <MapFileExtensions>true</MapFileExtensions>
    <ApplicationRevision>0</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.%2a</ApplicationVersion>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>false</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <UseApplicationTrust>false</UseApplicationTrust>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>true</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <SccProjectName>
    </SccProjectName>
    <SccLocalPath>
    </SccLocalPath>
    <SccAuxPath>
    </SccAuxPath>
    <SccProvider>
    </SccProvider>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>none</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <StartupObject>
    </StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x86'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\\x86\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x86'">
    <OutputPath>bin\\x86\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x86</PlatformTarget>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <CodeAnalysisRuleSet>MinimumRecommendedRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|x64'">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <OutputPath>bin\\x64\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\\x64\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
    <LangVersion>7.3</LangVersion>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="InstallerUtil">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\InstallerUtil.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.Core.CommonInterface">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\Core\CoreClient\Labcyte.Core.CommonInterface.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.Core.EventServer">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\Core\CoreClient\Labcyte.Core.EventServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.Core.Interface">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\Core\CoreClient\Labcyte.Core.Interface.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.EchoNET.Common, Version=0.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\Labcyte.EchoNET.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.EchoNET.Data, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\Labcyte.EchoNET.Data.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.EchoNET.EchoNETScripts, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\Labcyte.EchoNET.EchoNETScripts.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.EchoNET.HostServices">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\Labcyte.EchoNET.HostServices.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.EchoNET.Instrument, Version=0.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\Labcyte.EchoNET.Instrument.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.EchoNET.Interface, Version=0.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\Labcyte.EchoNET.Interface.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Labcyte.EchoNET.ServiceEndpoints, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\..\..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\Labcyte.EchoNET.ServiceEndpoints.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration.Install" />
    <Reference Include="System.IdentityModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
    <Reference Include="System.ServiceProcess" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Config.cs" />
    <Compile Include="EchoCallBack_HostService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Echo_HostService.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Host.cs">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ProjectInstaller.cs">
      <SubType>Component</SubType>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="ProjectInstaller.designer.cs">
      <DependentUpon>ProjectInstaller.cs</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs">
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTimeSharedInput>True</DesignTimeSharedInput>
      <DependentUpon>Settings.settings</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.config">
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </None>
    <None Include="Properties\Settings.settings">
      <Generator>SettingsSingleFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>Settings.Designer.cs</LastGenOutput>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Microsoft .NET Framework 4 %28x86 and x64%29</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
      <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Windows.Installer.3.1">
      <Visible>False</Visible>
      <ProductName>Windows Installer 3.1</ProductName>
      <Install>true</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <WCFMetadata Include="Service References\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Pico\Medman\AppsWrapper\AppsWrapper.vcxproj">
      <Project>hghjgj</Project>
      <Name>AppsWrapper</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Pico\Medman\FluidTransferInterface\FluidTransferInterface.csproj">
      <Project>434554</Project>
      <Name>FluidTransferInterface</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Pico\Medman\HarrierFluidTransfer\HarrierFluidTransfer.csproj">
      <Project>7686877</Project>
      <Name>HarrierFluidTransfer</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\EchoServerAPI\EchoServerAPI.csproj">
      <Project>89798798879</Project>
      <Name>EchoServerAPI</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Labcyte.Echo.EchoScripts\Labcyte.Echo.EchoScripts.csproj">
      <Project>7687687878787</Project>
      <Name>Labcyte.Echo.EchoScripts</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\EchoServerAPI.Server\EchoServerAPI.Server.csproj">
      <Project>76567687887</Project>
      <Name>EchoServerAPI.Server</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Labcyte.Echo.Commands\Labcyte.Echo.Commands.csproj">
      <Project>878989808899</Project>
      <Name>Labcyte.Echo.Commands</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML">
      <Version>2.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.CpuMath">
      <Version>2.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.DataView">
      <Version>2.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.OnnxRuntime">
      <Version>1.14.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ML.OnnxTransformer">
      <Version>2.0.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Mono.pdb2mdb">
      <Version>0.1.0.20130128</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation">
      <Version>4.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <EmbeddedResource Include="ProjectInstaller.resx">
      <DependentUpon>ProjectInstaller.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>rmdir /S /Q "$(TargetDir)ScriptClasses"
mkdir "$(TargetDir)ScriptClasses"
rmdir /S /Q "$(SolutionDir)..\Library\Echo\EchoServer"
mkdir "$(SolutionDir)..\Library\Echo\EchoServer"
mkdir "$(SolutionDir)..\Library\Echo\EchoServer\ScriptClasses"

</PreBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent>copy "$(TargetDir)*.dll"  "$(SolutionDir)..\Library\Echo\EchoServer"\"
copy "$(TargetDir)*.pdb"  "$(SolutionDir)..\Library\Echo\EchoServer"\"
copy  "$(SolutionDir)..\Library\EchoNET\EchoNETServer\ScriptClasses\*.cs" "$(TargetDir)ScriptClasses\"
copy  "$(TargetDir)ScriptClasses\" "$(SolutionDir)..\Library\Echo\EchoServer"\ScriptClasses\"
copy  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\\v4.8.1\Facades\System.Linq.*"  "$(TargetDir)"
copy  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\\v4.8.1\System.Core.dll"  "$(TargetDir)"
copy  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\\v4.8.1\Facades\\netstandard.dll"  "$(TargetDir)"
</PostBuildEvent>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. 
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target>
  -->
</Project>'''
    
    parseXMLInCsProj(xmlstr1)
```

### Edit

As suggested I updated my XML string. Now I don't see the error. But as soon as the debugger comes to the line  `for packageReference in tree.findall('.//PackageReference'):`, the program terminates. What can I try next?

Comment: It looks like the problem comes from `\v`, which is a special character in python.  Try making that xml string a raw string, i.e. use `xmlstr1=rf'''...`

Comment: Tried changing to rf but still the program terminates. Please see my edit.

Comment: That's a completely different error.  Using `rf` does fix the parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backslashes before `v` and `n` must be escaped to prevent being interpreted as escape codes themselves

```
copy  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\\v4.8.1\Facades\System.Linq.*"  "$(TargetDir)"
copy  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\\v4.8.1\System.Core.dll"  "$(TargetDir)"
copy  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\\v4.8.1\Facades\\netstandard.dll"  "$(TargetDir)"
```

`\v`    Vertical Tab
`\n`    Newline

```
print("a\vb\na  b")
a
 b
a  b
```

Escaped backslashes

```
print("a\\vb\\na  b")
a\vb\na  b
```

Also, there's a default namespace in the XML that needs to be taken into account

```
ns = {"x": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"}
print(tree.findall('.//x:PackageReference', ns))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I don't get the exception but when it comes to this line, the program just terminates. 
for packageReference in tree.findall('.//PackageReference'):

Comment: @nikhil namespaces are needed here. Check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much that gives me an idea. Let me try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use {*} PackageReference selects tags named PackageReference in any (or no) namespace:

```
for packageReference in tree.findall('.//{*}PackageReference'):
    print(elem.attrib)
```